# Как сделать возможность применения определенных стилей к выбранным через tab элементам?

Tags: html, css

На сайте Яндекса через tab можно выбирать элементы, к ним применяется стиль, обрамляющий элемент рамкой. Попробовал через :focus, но тогда все элементы выделяются, вне зависимости были выбраны они через таб или по нажатию мышки.

Comment: дак `tab` - это тот же самый `focus`, только по табиндексам....но при фокусе не все элементы должны обрамляться, а только тот, который вы зафокусили. По дефолту обрамляет в синий фон

Comment: Но если я выберу какой то элемент на главной Яндекса, я не увижу обводки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы это имеете ввиду?

```css
*:focus {
  outline-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0);">Outline on</a>
<p>Outline off</p>
<p tabIndex="0">Outline on text on</p>
```